# Using custom font in a UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, fonts, truetype

I would like to display a custom font inside a UIWebView. I have already put the font in the plist under "Fonts provided by application". The code in use:

```
        UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:myRect];
        NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
        [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseURL];
        [self addSubview:webView];
```

where html is an NSString that has the following contents:

```
<html><head>
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: gotham_symbol;
    src: local('GOTHAMboldSymbol_0.tff'), format('truetype') 
} 
body { 
 font-family: gotham_symbol;
font-size: 50pt;
}
</style>
</head><body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0">
This is <i>italic</i> and this is <b>bold</b> and this is some unicode: &#1101;
</body></html>
```

I'm using iOS 4.2 so TTF should be supported. I'd appreciate a bit of html/code that actually works.

Comment: `GOTHAMboldSymbol_0.tff` - extension should be `ttf` (unless the font really has a `tff` extension on disk).

Comment: I'm trying to find a solution to this too, but: I think you want to pass 'nil' for baseURL.

Comment: @Joris I struggle with the same problem at the moment and it would be interesting to hear if you have found a solution.

Comment: i posted my html below... let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 106, accepted):

After some Try and Error I have found a reliable way to load custom Fonts with a local CSS.

1. Add your Font to the App...make sure that the file is targeted
    properly to the Application

[image]
[image]

2. Then add your Font to yourApp-Info.plist

[image]

3. Run `NSLog(@"Available fonts: %@", [UIFont familyNames]);` To check which name the font/fontfamily has for the System...

[image]

4. Copy that name and use them in your CSS...@font-face is not needed

```
body {
    font-family:"Liberation Serif";
}
```

Comment: Sorry that I included that step. I had somehow assumed that you had done that step already...

Comment: Thank you! Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Step 1-3 is basically the standard way of adding custom fonts to an App...so yes it is documented. And in the last step you use the standard way of calling a font which is available on a system... :-)

Comment: can you explain the `Marker Felt` part in your css code? where did that come from?

Comment: Sorry if this CSS example was confusing...The Marker Felt part was completely unrelated and i have deleted it.

Comment: This only works for me every other time I build my app. I can't figure out why that is.

Comment: For the actual font names you should use: `[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:"Liberation Serif"]`

Comment: Brilliant , so accurate

Comment: It still works for the newest version iOS. mine environment is iOS SDK 11.2.

Answer (score 18):

I ended up making it work although I'm not sure what I did wrong above. Here's the HTML I use (NSString *htmll). I added everything, some of it might not be relevant for the solution.

```
<html><head><style type="text/css">
@font-face {
font-family: 'gotham_symbol';
src: url('GOTHAMboldSymbols_0.ttf')  format('truetype') 
}
@font-face {
font-family: 'gotham_symbol_italic';
src: url('GothamBoldItalic.ttf')  format('truetype') 
}
#w {display:table;}
#c {display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;}
i { font-family: 'Helvetica-BoldOblique'; }
</style></head><body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0">
<div style="display: table; width: 320px; height: 50px; #position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
<div style=" #position: absolute; #top: 50%;display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
<div style=" #position: relative; #top: -50%">
<p style="font-size:20px;font-family:'gotham_symbol';color:#97371f;">THE TEXT GOES HERE</p></div></div></div></body></html>
```

and I load the UIWebView as follows:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
[webView makeTransparent];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseURL];
```

Comment: strange enough the other solution by Lindemann does not work for me, but this did work.

Answer (score 7):

For Swift and WKWebView, this worked for me:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!


let html = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Raleway-Regular';
            src: url('Raleway-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype')
        }
        img {
            width: 100%;
        }
        body {
            font-family: 'Raleway-Regular';
            font-size: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    My HTML Content
</body>
</html>
"""


let baseURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.bundlePath)
webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: baseURL)
```

The fonts have to be added to the XCode project as you would normally do, and Copy bundle resources

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>Raleway-Bold.ttf</string>
    <string>Raleway-Regular.ttf</string>
</array>
```

Comment: In my case, baseURL was the secret, thank you.

Comment: Does the font need to be in the same directory as the html?

Comment: I added the explanation relating the font inclusion.