# WKWebView delegate issue (Xcode 7.3 using Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, wkwebview

I am creating an app that is essentially a webview. It uses custom, proprietary fonts that cannot be used in a regular webapp, hence the app wrapper.

It works fine for most purposes but I wanted to check if a URL request loaded properly, to send a 'page not found' message or some such when a bad URL is given or the URL fails to load. For this I believe I need a delegate.

Problem: every time I try to create a delegate (despite trying a few ways I've seen in examples) the app just crashes on load.

(By the way: if I create the webview programmatically rather than in the storyboard, the custom fonts do not load, which for my purposes is a failure of the main requirement. Please keep this in mind if you have a solution)

Code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

@IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!
var screenEdgeRecognizer: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer!
//var currentRadius:CGFloat = 0.0

@IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    screenEdgeRecognizer = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self,
        action: #selector(ViewController.goBack(_:)))
    screenEdgeRecognizer.edges = .Left
    view.addGestureRecognizer(screenEdgeRecognizer)

    // *** This line commented out to prevent app from crashing!
    //self.webView.navigationDelegate = self

    webView.hidden = false;
    // this allows the UIWebView box to your background color seamlessly.
    webView.opaque = false;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let url = NSURL (string: "http://localhost/web_app/mobile_login.php");

    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);

    //let localfilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("home", withExtension: "html");
    //let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: localfilePath!);
    webView.loadRequest(requestObj);
    //webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true;

}

// **** This code I hope to use but I think requires a delegate in order to work
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: NSError) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil))
    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {

    //LightContent
    return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent

    //Default
    //return UIStatusBarStyle.Default

}

func goBack(sender: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer) {
    //

    self.webView.goBack()

}
```

}

Many thanks for advice.

Comment: it's the bit that's commented out with //***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot yet create a `WKWebView` in Interface Builder. I believe it has to be created programmatically. Are you using a `UIWebView` in the storyboard and trying to setup the outlet as a `WKWebView`? If so, that's why it is crashing. They are different objects altogether.

You could try using UIWebView if you must build it in Storyboard. But I don't know why `WKWebView` would behave any differently when created programmatically (well it can't be created in IB in the first place).

Comment: That would explain it. I started this project a while back with a UIwebview and must have changed it to a WKwebview in code based on someone's example, and it worked until I tried to add a delegate. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Mike Cole's answer above got to the heart of what my problem was. But also FYI on further investigation, I discovered this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785179/using-custom-fonts-in-wkwebview) which looks at custom fonts and the difficulties using them with WKWebViews