# Insert @font-face into a WKWebView

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I want to use custom fonts in a `WKWebView`.

I use `insertCSSString(into webView: WKWebView)`, but as soon as I add `"@font-face{font-family: 'Roboto-BlackItalic'; url('Roboto-BlackItalic.ttf') format('truetype');}"` to the string the css appears not not be evaluated (in this example the colour of any text does not change to red).

The approach is taken from [Using custom fonts in WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785179/using-custom-fonts-in-wkwebview)

So the question is - how can I use custom fonts with this approach. I have tried the following:

```
extension DetailViewController {
    func insertCSSString(into webView: WKWebView) {
        let cssString = "@font-face{font-family: 'Roboto-BlackItalic'; url('Roboto-BlackItalic.ttf') format('truetype');} body { font-size: 20px; color: red; background-color: clear; } htesttwo {color: black; }"
        let jsString = "var style = document.createElement('style'); style.innerHTML = '\(cssString)'; document.head.appendChild(style);"
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(jsString, completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your font file ? is it on your device? , because fontface run from the server that you have your html code there and you use the fontface in your app, so you have to have the font file on your device

Comment: Yes, the fonts are on the device.

Answer (score 0):

you should just put your fonts into your project after that create a css file and put the fontface code there like that

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'MonotypeSabonW04-Regular';
    src: local('MonotypeSabonW04-Regular'),url('Monotype Sabon Regular.otf') format('opentype');
}
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'MonotypeSabonW04-Italic';
    src: local('MonotypeSabonW04-Italic'),url('Monotype Sabon Italic.otf') format('opentype');
}

@font-face
{
    font-family: 'CharlotteSansW02-Book';
    src: local('CharlotteSansW02-Book'),url('Charlotte Sans Book.otf') format('opentype');
}


h1
{
    font-family: 'MonotypeSabonW04-Regular';
    font-size: 70px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

h2
{
    font-family: 'MonotypeSabonW04-Italic';
    font-size: 65px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

h3
{
    font-family: 'CharlotteSansW02-Book';
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

after put the fonts file on the css folder and load it with followfing sample

```
let strCssHead = "<head><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"iPhone.css\"></head>"
let strbody = "<body> <h1>Font 1</h1> <h2>Font 2</h2> <h3>Font 3</h3> </body>"
        wkweb.loadHTMLString("\(strCssHead)\(strbody)", baseURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "iPhone", ofType: "css")!))
```

Comment: @stevenpcurtis Here is a sample for you : https://medium.com/if-let-swift-programming/css-in-your-xcode-project-2b7011a29cb3

Comment: How can I load any font remotely during the runtime for that?

Comment: @AmirHajihaI didn't do it by myself, but I think if you download them and register them you can use them in the app same as the current example , for more info about how to register a remote font refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/72455701/3992606