# Replace UIWebView with WKWebView - Fonts not getting applies

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview, xcode11

I have updated UIWebView to WKWebView. Fonts are not getting applies you can check following attached screen shots.

Fonts .ttf files are added in project. also in Copy Bundle Resources.

```
self.webView.loadHTMLString(textHtml, baseURL: Bundle.main.bundleURL)
```

[[image][image: on]

Added font-face in style.

```css
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'Lato-Bold';
    src: url(Lato-Bold.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

Using Xcode 11.3. Any missing link ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: double-check this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785179/using-custom-fonts-in-wkwebview

Comment: @DamyanTodorov same i have checked multiple types. Could not get help from it.

Comment: try loading this style as css using user script while initialising WKWebview as described here: https://www.amerhukic.com/determining-the-content-size-of-a-wkwebview