# UILabel set bold font with sans-serif

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to set bold font for `UILabel` as follows :

```
lblActivities.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"sans-serif-Bold" size:15.0];
```

But this is not appearing as bold.
Any suggestions?

Comment: used NSAttributedString for this

Comment: @SumitGarg : But how to set all : font name, bold and size?

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct font name? Check against font family names in applicationDidFinishLaunching and it will display exactly the name. It might not need the hyphens for example

Comment: i don't see that font as being available.  should also note you can add your own font in if you have your heart set on a particular one.

Comment: sans-serif is not a system font that is reason.try `helvetica-bold`

Comment: @SumitGarg : So is helvetica same as sans-serif ?

Comment: both are font name but sans-serif not is a predefine font name but helvetica is predefine font name in xcode.

Comment: @SumitGarg : I applied helvetica instead. But the fonts are different.

Comment: see my edited answer, you have to download sans-serif.ttf file for your font and follow step which was describe in provided link that's it.

Comment: helvetica just a example.

Comment: san serif font just means "without serifs", serifs being the little "tails" added to the characters like in a serif font (e.g. Times Roman).  Generally the "default" sans-serif font is Helvetica, but sometimes arial.  Have you tried just [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15] ?  that's usually a bold san serif font.

Comment: check font family in font book and add this code `lblActivities.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"fontFamilyName" size:15.0];`

Answer (score 2):

1-You need your font in .otf or .ttf copied to your project. For example in Supporting Files.

2 - You need to edit .plist file.

3 - Add "Fonts provided by application" key into your plist and in Item 0 copy the exact filename of the font you copied to your Supporting files WITH extension. For example: "`JosefinSansStd-Light_0.otf`"

4 - Make sure that the font you imported to your app is being packed into app itself. Do that by selecting your Target, then Build Phases, then Copy Bundle Resources. If you don't see your font in there, drag it from Supporting Files.

5 - Finally, you would like to list all your fonts when the app starts just to see useable name for your font. You will do that with this little piece of code:

```
NSArray *fontFamilies = [UIFont familyNames];
for (int i = 0; i < [fontFamilies count]; i++)
{
 NSString *fontFamily = [fontFamilies objectAtIndex:i];
 NSArray *fontNames = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:[fontFamilies objectAtIndex:i]];
 NSLog (@"%@: %@", fontFamily, fontNames);
}
```

Search for your font in printed results, for example, I would search for "Josefin" and I would see that actual font name is `"JosefinSansStd-Light"`. After that you only need to use that font by:

```
UIFont *customFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"JosefinSansStd-Light" size:20];
```

**In iOS8 you add your fonts directly to the project and they are visible in the interface builder.** Modify your code to account for this but programmatically setting font for iOS7 and selecting it in xCode6 interface builder. PS. Interface builder in xCode6 gives you the correct font name that you can copy-paste into the code below.

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)

if(SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"8.0"))
   {
       UIFont *customFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Light" size:32];
       self.registerLabel.font = customFont;  
   }
```

Hope this helps, cheers.

[For More Information check This Post](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/)

Answer (score 0):

you have direct option in Xcode 
1. select the label on view controller
2. on your right hand side panel select attribute inspector .
3. select font  text-box link 
4. a alert box appear select font dropdownlist 
5 select custom from that list
6 set your style bold from style dropdown

Answer (score -1):

try this may be help you. **Make sure the font name is correct or available in your application.**

```
[lblActivities setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"sans-serif-Bold" size:15.0]];
```

The Font which you describe is not available in apple library **by Default** you have to use custom font for this.

see Below link

[Using custom font in a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490696/using-custom-font-in-a-uiwebview)

Comment: some times setFont working instead of using property.