# How to include custom font in UIWebview?

Tags: ios, swift3, uiwebview

how to  include custom font added in info.plist into html page of webview.
html  is included as string

currently including font as

```
 @font-face{font-family:'PrStart';src:local('PrStart'),url('PrStart.otf') format('opentype');}
```

but it is not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using custom font in a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490696/using-custom-font-in-a-uiwebview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
let string = "<font face='font-name' size='2'>" + "Your String"
```

and load webview from this string.