# Custom Font Not Working in WKWebView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, wkwebview

Trying to use custom font in WKWebView but no luck.

```
let htmlString = "<span style=\"font-family: 'OpenSans-Bold'; font-size: 30; color: white\">\(Utils.aboutUsText)</span>"
webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
```

I can use HelveticaNeue-Bold and works great but not with the custom font above.

```
let htmlString = "<span style=\"font-family: 'HelveticaNeue'; font-size: 30; color: white\">\(Utils.aboutUsText)</span>"
webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
```

I have added the custom fonts properly.See screenshots.

Can someone please tell me how can i achieve this or point me in the right direction.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/10490696

Comment: Yes i have as you can see in my screenshots.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using custom fonts in WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785179/using-custom-fonts-in-wkwebview)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Reading the answers in [the linked thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25785179/6541007) in DonMag's comment:

- Using `@font-face` is mandatory
- You need multiple `@font-face` declarations to use multiple font files as a single font family
- You need to provide `baseURL` to make relative urls like `url(OpenSans-Regular.ttf)` work

So, try this:

```
    let htmlString = """
    <style>
    @font-face
    {
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        font-weight: normal;
        src: url(OpenSans-Regular.ttf);
    }
    @font-face
    {
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        font-weight: bold;
        src: url(OpenSans-Bold.ttf);
    }
    @font-face
    {
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        font-weight: 900;
        src: url(OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf);
    }
    @font-face
    {
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        font-weight: 200;
        src: url(OpenSans-Light.ttf);
    }
    @font-face
    {
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        font-weight: 500;
        src: url(OpenSans-Semibold.ttf);
    }
    </style>
    <span style="font-family: 'Open Sans'; font-weight: bold; font-size: 30; color: red">(Utils.aboutUsText)</span>
    """
    webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: Bundle.main.bundleURL) //<-
```

---

Or you can use a separate css file if you prefer:

```
    let htmlString = """
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="open-sans.css">
    <span style="font-family: 'Open Sans'; font-weight: bold; font-size: 30; color: red">(Utils.aboutUsText)</span>
    """
    webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: Bundle.main.bundleURL)
```

open-sans.css:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url(OpenSans-Regular.ttf);
}
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: bold;
    src: url(OpenSans-Bold.ttf);
}
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: 900;
    src: url(OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf);
}
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: 200;
    src: url(OpenSans-Light.ttf);
}
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: 500;
    src: url(OpenSans-Semibold.ttf);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for showing `baseURL: Bundle.main.bundleURL`

Comment: I also have some social feeds to our web content. I lose all the social feeds if baseURL is Bundle.main.bundleURL.

Comment: Struggled for a long while until figure out about `baseURL: Bundle.main.bundleURL`, thank you very much!

Comment: Do you know why `src: local(...)` doesn't work but url does?

Comment: @Harout360, I do not know much about `src: local`, but the core part of `WKWebView` runs in another process (not just another thread, but another process), so fonts embedded in an app bundle might not be considered to be  _local_.

Answer (score -1):

```
class StaticContentViewControlle:  WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var webViewContainer: UIView!
    private var webView: WKWebView?
    var url = ""
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        initialSetup()
    }
    
    func initialSetup() {
        url = "https://www.apple.com"
        
        let myURL = URL(string: url)
        if let myURL = myURL {
            let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL)
            webView?.uiDelegate = self
            webView?.load(myRequest)
        }
        webView?.navigationDelegate = self
        webView?.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        webView?.scrollView.backgroundColor = .clear
        webView?.isOpaque = false
        webView?.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("Start loading")
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("End loading")
        let textSize = 300
        let javascript = "document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '\(textSize)%'"
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(javascript) { (response, error) in
            print()
        }
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated  {
            if let url = navigationAction.request.url,
                UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                decisionHandler(.cancel)
            } else {
                print("Open it locally")
                decisionHandler(.allow)
            }
        } else {
            print("not a user click")
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
    }
}
```