# WKWebview is not showing proper font from remote URL

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I am loading a remote url in WKWebview where only content is text. Text is loading properly but there in site they used 'Nunito' font, which is not showing here in my side. When i open url in browser text are showing properly with font even in safari borowser.

> Here is my Code

```
let urlStr = "http://islamintel.com/cms/about-us"
            if let url = URL(string: urlStr) {
                let request = URLRequest(url: url)
                wkWebView.load(request)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add custom font (i.e Nunito) in the app. Here is the reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49370238/custom-font-not-working-in-wkwebview-swift?rq=1) on how to load custom font in WKWebView.

Comment: Font is added to my project adn my url is remote. "I am not loading local html"